# Copying ArrayList to text file using methods

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I want to remove elements from an arraylist with the method:

```
 public static String removeOldestItem(ArrayList<String> theList)
```

and to write the removed elements to a text file using this method:

```
 public static void addItem(ArrayList<String> theList, String s)
```

So far I have:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList <String> s = new ArrayList<> (4); 
        s.add("Knock knock.");
        s.add("Who's there?");
        s.add("*very long pause....*");
        s.add("Java");


         try {
                FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("list_contents.txt");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

                for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {

                    out.write(String.valueOf(s.get(i) ) );
                    out.write("\r\n");
                } 
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
 }
```

The second method should place the String “s” into the passed list “theList”.  The first method should remove the item that has been in the list the longest and return that item to the caller.

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement the methods.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to implement new methods for the ArrayList<> class or something different?

Comment: These are methods my teacher named, so they aren't new methods, just methods I need to write

Comment: Okay, so you need to figure out a way to tell what the oldest element is.  Tricky bit about arraylist is it has elements to insert at any reference point, and no way that I know of to tell how old something is.  If we ignore inserting at a particular point and assume you insert only at the "end" you could create an iterator to track the "oldest" item and assume the item immediately after it in the array is the next oldest.  Since we are controlling the insert method as well, this seems like a safe idea

Comment: Say the index 0 is the oldest, can I use a for loop to count all the up to 3 to keep adding elements into the list? If so, will I need to implement this in both methods, or are they outside the methods?

Comment: Look at the iterator object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html  and the iterator method of the ArrayList class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()   Basically its an object that keeps your place in a data object like an ArrayList.  You can then tell it to go to the next object, delete the object, etc.  You could use the Iterator's place to denote the oldest object.  Then when you want to remove the object, delete it and move the iterator.  Play around with it and see what works best for you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a removeOldestItem method on ArrayList, however linked lists and linked hash maps have `removeEldestEntry`. It is generally overridden to produce a cache with some sort of smart pruning.

Is your goal to extend ArrayList and an OutputStream by adding a couple convenience methods?

Comment: Not extending, per se, but rather writing the elements to the text file via the above methods. Well, I guess what you're suggesting is correct.